# Why does Python packages run in IDLE 3.7 but not in Atom?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently installed Python 3.7 on my Mac and downloaded Atom with the 'Run' script so that I can run Python and its packages on Atom.

However, I am not managing to run Python packages in Atom (just in IDLE 3.7). I made a test by just importing pandas into it. I installed the Python packages using 'pip install package_name'.

The options that I have to run Python are:
[image]

The message that appears is:
[image]

Python packages run successfully only on IDLE 3.7. I might have downloaded other Python versions in the past, but I have already uninstalled and installed again newer ones.

I just would like to have one Python version on my Mac - the most recent one. How can I sort out this problem?

Comment: Check your project interpreter, you should use your system default environment. Some IDE will create a virtual environment that has no package installed.

Comment: How can I make the IDE use the same environment then?

Comment: So for Atom you need to install `atom-runner` package to run scripts inside the editor. Then in the editor hit `ctrl + R` you can run your script. You might need to config the runner (all in the documents) to make it work properly.